# Why are so many old lamps switching the neutral wire?

Tags: switches, home-installation

So I am deconstructing old houses and I noticed that there are many Lamps that are switching the Neutral Wire instead of the Phase.

Why was this done ( Especially as it has no advantages afaik)

Comment: In older houses (especially those with knob & tube wiring), they often didn't make a distinction between "neutral" and "phase". They simply treated both wires as being equally dangerous.

Comment: Maybe no advantage, but a definite disadvantage.

Comment: It could be that in those days the supply was split phase type, i.e. both wires were live. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-phase_electric_power , then someday the electric company changed in single phase with live and neutral. Other possibility is that the electrician had poor knowledge, still today lot of people "know" how to wire a home.

Comment: I seem to recall that in some instances, wire/hole drilling can be saved by switching the neutral on 3-way switch circuits.  Probably against code?  Carter wiring?

Comment: Not "Carter Wiring" but "Carter System": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#Carter_system

Comment: They also could think that connecting a live wire on a poorly insulated switch presented a electric shock hazard. Later, one noticed that the hazard came much more often from replacing the bulb. As the isolation of the swiches increased in quality with the invention of new plastics, the risk at the switch became minimal.